# Set Width of a View Programmatically React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal list of Views in react native. Views have different widths.

How can I set the width of each element equal to the widest one?

I have tried:

```
const textViewRef = useRef<any>([]);

textViewRef.current = btnData.map((_, i) => textViewRef.current[i] ?? createRef());

const ref = useRef<TouchableOpacity | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    let maxWidth = 0;
    for (const el of textViewRef.current) {
        el.current?.measure((x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number, pageX: number, pageY: number) => {
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = width;
            if (el.current) {
                if (el.current.style) {
                    el.current.style.minWidth = maxWidth;
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}, [textViewRef.current]);


<FlatList
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
horizontal
data={btnData}
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 0 }}
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
<TouchableOpacity ref={textViewRef.current[index] as any} key={index} style={[styles.navBtn]}>
    <Body2>{item.title}</Body2>
</TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```